# Eclipse auto-complete for JavaServer Faces 1.2 for xhtml files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, autocomplete, xhtml

I have used the methods below.

Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Add (xhtml) -> done

Right click on the project -> Preferences -> Project Facets -> Click on "JavaServer Faces", version should most probably be 1.2 -> done,

I have also installed JBoss tools and code completion sort of works. You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for it to give you options. I think this is a bit cumbersome and is not real code auto-completion you would expect from an IDE.

I have seen proper code auto-completion in intelliJ and Netbeans for JSF Xhtml files. The current mechanism for code auto-complete is sub-par is there a way for Eclipse (Juno) to get proper code completion? i.e without having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Unfortunately I am stuck having to use Eclipse so your help will be really appreciated in regard to getting proper code auto-completion.

Comment: Eclipse code auto-completion works with Ctrl+Space. Don't know how it works in IntelliJ and Netbeans, but that's the way Eclipse does it.

Comment: I guess I cannot fight against the IDE, its a shame. Thanks for your assistance.